# Provide a way to see a moderator candidate's questions that you have interacted with

Tags: feature-request, moderators, election

On the [vote for moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/vote-moderator) page, provide a way to see questions that you have "in common" with the potential moderators.

I would like to see perhaps a button (with a count) for each candidate that shows me which questions I have asked/answered/commented on that that candidate has been active on as well.  It would be GREAT to see direct actions (moderations of my entries) highlighted.

What I'm looking for is how the candidate performs on questions with which I'm already familiar and situations where I participated.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35089/whats-your-jon-skeet-number

Comment: I agree that this would be very interesting to see, if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably faster if you search these entries yourself, instead of waiting that this gets implemented. I picked one candidate randomly:

> ["chris nava" welbog site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.de/search?hl=en&q=%22chris+nava%22+welbog+site%3Astackoverflow.com&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=)

Comment: Cool, I changed it from welbog to mmyers and this question showed up... twice.

Comment: works even better if you add `inurl:questions` to the query.

Comment: Neat!  It didn't even occur to me to use Google as a database for this data.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, none of us are moderators yet. I do think it would be neat to show some basic statistics about the user beside their name though. How long they've been a member, what their current reputation is. How many questions, answers, badges, etc.

Comment: ... average number of question views per day and average number of edits to other's posts per day.  Those are the big one for me as far as moderator-worthiness goes.

Comment: @Joel: If that was your criteria, just pencil me in.

Comment: ... and does it without causing a stink.

Comment: Oh, and number of times per day they check the moderator tools link.

Comment: My intent was not to find folks who cause a stink or don't.  I'm interested to find ones who have handled a situation that I saw develop.  I think it would be better than reading examples of their work out of context after the fact.

Comment: I agree that basic stats on the listing page would be a good start.  Do you think it would influence the voting too much to see just stats without examples?