# See comparison between me and someone else (like Facebooks "You and David" view)

Tags: feature-request

From time to time I run across a profile of someone I know I've interacted with before. I rarely remember where and in what context however.

I'm thinking of something similar to Facebooks *"You and David... See Friendship"*-view of me and this other person.

Such page could for instance list

- Discussions we've had (in chat and comments)
- Which questions we've both answered
- Which of his questions I answered
- Which of my questions he answered
- Which of his questions, answers and comments I've voted on

etc.

Perhaps such feature would be heavy on the database. On the other hand it doesn't really matter if such view is updated on say, a weekly basis, since more recent interactions are usually fresh in memory anyway...

Comment: What benefit would it give to the core business of asking and answering questions?

Comment: It would make it even more fun, just as badges I suppose :-)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35089/whats-your-jon-skeet-number

Comment: Badges are not used just for fun; they are used to promote a specific behavior.

Comment: ...This is not a social networking site.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree that this would really improve the functionality and match the purpose of stack exchange sites, but I agree that it would be very cool and interesting. My request would simply be to have a little menu that shows questions you've answered for each other.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly doubt the usefulness of this, but [here's a data explorer query that somewhat does this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1763/who-have-i-interacted-with). It gives you all question where both of the given users either have an answer (or are the question owner), or are involved in a comment thread (either as commenter, or as post owner).

Note that this query is pretty slow, in particular on SO, it takes quite a while.

Comment: Wow, nice. The whole thing is probably actually better suited as a data explorer query :-) And I agree.. it's not really *useful* in that sense :-)